# Does an I-130 and pending I-485 affect my H1-B Visa?

Tags: usa, visa, h1-visa

I know merely filing an I-130 can change quite bit of things regarding immigration. Is it safe to travel on an H1-B if you have an approved I-130 and a pending I-485?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just called U.S. Customs and Border Protection regarding this question. They informed that,

- An H1-B is different then any other visa (except an L1 per comments), (perhaps because of [Dual Intent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_intent)), you can enter on an H1-B even if you filed an I-130.
- Exiting and leaving on an H1-B will not invalidate your I-485 application or cause it be seen as abandoned.

I was pointed to the [website for Advance Parole](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/advance-parole) which says,

> Aliens applying for advance parole on the basis of a pending application for adjustment of status must be approved for advance parole prior to leaving the United States in order to avoid the termination of their pending application for adjustment. **Note: this does not apply to aliens who have applied to adjust to permanent resident status and who maintain H-1B (Specialty Worker) or L-1 (Intracompany Transferee) status**, or their dependents, who have applied to adjust to permanent resident status and who have valid H-1B or L status and valid visas, V nonimmigrants who have a valid V nonimmigrant visa, are in valid V nonimmigrant status and have or obtain a valid V nonimmigrant visa before applying for readmission to the US, and K-3/4 nonimmigrants who have applied to adjust to permanent resident status and who have a valid K-3/4 nonimmigrant visa, are in valid K-3/4 nonimmigrant status and have or obtain a valid K-3/4 nonimmigrant visa before applying for readmission to the US.

Comment: This is also true for L1 visas as well. H1 and L1 visas are "dual intent".